# Building webpack vendor files in subdirectories

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to output vendor (cacheGroup) files from webpack into the same directory as my main module files. Best explained showing some webpack config.

Currently the config is:

```
var config = {
  mode: mode,
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    "Client": "./Client/entry.coffee",
    "Public": "./Public/entry.coffee",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "Build", environment),
    filename: environment === "production" ? "[name]/Assets/bundle-[hash].js" : "[name]/Assets/bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
```

I am trying to split out the vendor cache groups via:

```
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: (chunk) => {
        return chunk.name.startsWith("client");// || chunk.name == "Public";
      },
      automaticNameDelimiter: "-",
      name: true,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

This will output files in a structure when I run webpack, roughly like:

```sh
./Build/dev/Client/Assets/bundle.js
./Build/dev/vendor-Client/Assets/vendor-Client.js
```

But I want it to be

```sh
./Build/dev/Client/Assets/bundle.js
./Build/dev/Client/Assets/vendor-Client.js
```

There just seems to be no way to change the directory of vendor files to match.

Answer (score 0):

For this line of code you are doing wrong

```
filename: environment === "production" ? "[name]/Assets/bundle-[hash].js" : "[name]/Assets/bundle.js",
```

For this line `[name]/Assets/bundle.js`

You are using the [name] so it build into this like `1/Assets/bundle.js` `2/Assets/bundle.js`

So you must change to

```
Assets/[name].bundle.js
```

So everything will be build into assets folder

Comment: Yes, if that was how I was going to store the files, however, that is not the case.